# Load initial data in Play 2.0+

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm creating a Play framework application, and I need to load in some data. The framework (I've done some work with it when it was at 1.2.4, and now I've been trying out 2.0.3) used to support the creation of a `data.yaml` file, which could be loaded in on runtime.

Support for this appears to have been dropped. What is the best practice for going about this now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope, it wasn't dropped, just refactored. The main weight was moved to the the [Global object](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaGlobal) and its `onStart()` method.

Using it you can perform common DB operations as well you can also load and traverse **any** `YAML` file. Check the [Zentasks sample](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/samples/java/zentasks) to see how to use it in your own app (especially: `app/Global.java`, `conf/initial-data.yml`); for instance, from the [sample](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/samples/java/zentasks/app/Global.java):

```
Map<String,List<Object>> all = (Map<String,List<Object>>)Yaml.load("initial-data.yml");
```

It's just beginning! Using `Global object` depends only on your imaginary!

Comment: the zen tasks link is broken

Comment: Indeed, the zen tasks links is broken. 
Some quick github searching did provide other correct links. 
Just in case someone else searches this, some quicker links: 
 https://github.com/jamesward/zentasks/blob/master/app/Global.java
 
 https://github.com/akskscala/zentasks-collections/blob/master/squeryl/app/Global.scala