# Play 2, Load data to database on start

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

Fortunatly we have evolution in play framework 2 so we don't care about schema (if we want). My question is, is there any practice with loading data to the database on application startup? I suppose that I can load it with Global object, but what the approach needs less code and more flexible(in java)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look on the [same question (and answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12013405/1066240), the official way is showed in Zentasks sample.

you can also use [common evolutions to insert data in raw SQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11949581/1066240)L format (it doesn't work only with schema)